# Agendamento dinamico de tarefas com spring batch + quartz

Tags: java, aplicação-web, spring, scheduler

Tenho um projecto em Spring Batch + quartz, que carrega um ficheiro processando em seguida os dados do ficheiro. Só que queria implementar uma view com um formulário onde tinha a opção de escolher a hora inicio e hora fim  e os dias onde poderia correr.
Consigo fazer essa funcionalidade com o quartz + Spring batch ?

Obrigado pela atenção

Answer (score 1):

É possível sim, os comandos do Spring Scheduler podem ser ajustados programaticamente. Mais detalhes [aqui](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-trigger-implementations)

É só persistir os dados da sua view e criar uma nova `CronTrigger` com os dados de execução.

Comment: hm ok, obrigado pela dica. Vou investigar :)

Answer (score 0):

Olá! As versões mais atuais do Spring, permite que você crie um método e agende a execução dele com uma anotação Cron. Para isso basta seguir algumas dicas. Vamos a elas:

```
@Component
class Agendador {
  //Tarefa agendada para todos os dias a 00:00
  @Scheduled(cron="0 0 0 * * *")
  public void tarefaAgendada() {
    //Codigo da sua tarefa
  }
}
```

Isso com certeza deve resolver seu problema!